# Using purrr to help transform a large data file

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, lubridate

I have a bit of code that goes through a number of columns containing dates and selects the earliest date from the options to populate a new column with. To do this I was using the `dplyr::rowwise` function.

Unfortunately, the data set is quite big and comes at a time cost in obtaining an output. Here is an example of my initial approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(101)

data <- tibble(date1 = sample(
  seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
  100, replace = TRUE),
  date2 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
    100, replace = TRUE),
  date3 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
    100, replace = TRUE),
  date4 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
    100, replace = TRUE),
  date5 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
    100, replace = TRUE))
```

So for the first attempt I opted for `rowwise`. I hadn't used this before, but the output is identified as 'rowwise_df', which I take to be similar if I had used `group_by`.

```
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(earlierst_date = min(c(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5),
                              na.rm = TRUE))
```

Having looked around, it would appear that rowwise is not considered the best approach ([see excellent back and forth here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-alternatives-to-rowwise/8071)). Reading through, I attempted the following...

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(try_again = pmap(list(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5), 
                          min, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(try_again = as_date(try_again))

table(data$earlierst_date == data$try_again)
#> 
#> TRUE 
#>  100
```

According to my `reprex` run the second option is twice as fast.

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(earlierst_date = min(c(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5),
                              na.rm = TRUE))
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
#> Time difference of 0.07597804 secs

start.time <- Sys.time()
data <- data %>%
  mutate(try_again = pmap(list(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5), 
                          min, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(try_again = as_date(try_again))
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
#> Time difference of 0.03266287 secs
```

**My questions:**

**1.** Is the second strategy using pmap fit for purpose or is there some inherent error present that I can't see? For example, in earlier attempts, the output column contained list values rather than vectors which threw me.

I get dizzy anytime I have to work with dates, especially when I read comments such as "A date is a day stored as the number of days since 1970-01-01"...

**2.** Do the code run times make sense?

Any improvements/direction greatly received.

Comment: I think if the speed of execution matters most for your purpose, you have to seek a `data.table` solution.

Comment: I don't know if that's the case here - I tested out a data.table method and it was slightly slower - maybe someone else can come up with a faster implementation / alternative solution

Comment: @jared_mamrot I am so sorry I didn't realize you posted one `data.table` solution in your benchmark. I deleted mine.

Comment: No problem at all @AnoushiravanR - was your method different to mine? I'd be very interested to see if your data.table solution was faster

Comment: Thank you, No it was almost the same as yours, I just failed to find it among your solutions. I don't think there is anything left to mention here now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @det that rowwise isn't the way to go. I think perhaps the pmin function might be the best suited to the task, e.g.

```
data <- transform(data, earliest_date = pmin(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Benchmarking (updated to include a data.table solution):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(101)

data <- tibble(date1 = sample(
  seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
  100, replace = TRUE),
  date2 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
                 100, replace = TRUE),
  date3 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
                 100, replace = TRUE),
  date4 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
                 100, replace = TRUE),
  date5 = sample(seq(ymd('2021-03-20'), ymd('2021-05-20'), by = 'day'), 
                 100, replace = TRUE))

rowwise_func <- function(data){
  data %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(earliest_date = min(c(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5),
                               na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    ungroup()
}

pmap_func <- function(data){
  data %>% 
    mutate(try_again = pmap(list(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5), 
                          min, na.rm = TRUE))
  }

det_func1 <- function(data){
  data %>%
  mutate(min_date = pmap_dbl(select(., matches("^date")), min) %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01"))
}

det_faster <- function(data){
  data[["min_date"]] <- data %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.Date), as.integer)) %>% 
    as.matrix() %>% 
    apply(1, function(x) x[which.min(x)]) %>%
    as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")
}

transform_func <- function(data){
  as_tibble(transform(data, earliest_date = pmin(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, na.rm = TRUE)))
}

dt_func <- function(data){
  setDT(data)
  data[, earliest_date := pmin(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, na.rm = TRUE)]
}

times <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(rowwise_func(data), pmap_func(data), det_func1(data), det_faster(data), transform_func(data), dt_func(data))
autoplot(times)

data2 <- transform_func(data)
data3 <- rowwise_func(data)
identical(data2, data3)
#> TRUE
```

[image: example_3.png]

```
Unit: microseconds
                 expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
   rowwise_func(data) 6764.693 6919.6720 7375.0418 7066.6220 7271.5850  16290.696   100  ab
      pmap_func(data) 3994.973 4150.1360 9425.3880 4252.9850 4437.2950 491030.248   100   b
      det_func1(data) 5576.240 5724.6820 6249.7573 5845.3305 5985.5940  15106.741   100  ab
     det_faster(data) 3182.016 3305.3525 3556.8628 3362.8720 3444.0505  12771.952   100  ab
 transform_func(data)  564.194  624.1055  697.5630  680.1130  718.7975   1513.184   100  a 
        dt_func(data)  650.611  723.7235  956.7916  759.3355  782.0565  10806.902   100  a
```

So, based on the functions I used above, the transform + pmin method was ~ 10X faster than the rowwise method.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to demonstrate those stark differences.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for including all the necessary info in your question (sample data and your attempts to solve the problem)

Answer (score 2):

From my experiance `rowwise` is extremely slow so I prefer using any other option  (at the cost of having less tidy code) especially if I have numeric columns (then I convert to matrix). `pmap` is definitely option, but sometimes I have trouble listing all needed columns (doesn't have tidy select option). This can be somewhat avoided by using `select` within `pmap`:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(min_date = pmap_dbl(select(., matches("^date")), min) %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

Converting to matrix was usually fastest way (much faster) for my problems (in combination with function like `apply` or `sweep`:

```
data[["min_date"]] <- data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.Date), as.integer)) %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  apply(1, function(x) x[which.min(x)]) %>%
  as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")
```